# Google Load Balancer SSL certificate only valid in browser

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have a Google HTTPS Load Balancer in front of a Cloud Run and a Google Storage bucket. I bought a wildcard SSL certificate for my domain from ZeroSSL and added it to the Load Balancer. The routing works fine and I can use everything as intended. If I open a URL in any browser, it confirms that the certificate is valid. However, if I send a request from insomnia with SSL validation enabled, I get the following error:

```
Error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

I get a similar error if I send a request from a NodeJS script or from another server. How can this be fixed? All our customers have the same issue, sending requests to our service. Letting them add the certificate on their side is not an option.

I bought another certificate from Sectigo, but the behavior is the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell for sure without knowing the domain to check. But a common cause of the problem you describe are missing intermediate certificates. Browsers typically successfully work around such configuration errors, other clients don't. Check your site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look out for "chain issues" or similar.

Comment: Most likely you installed the public certificate without including the certificate chain. Your question lacks details such as the domain name, certificate configuration, etc. That information is public, there is no need to mask it in your question, and providing that information makes it possible to tell you exactly what is wrong.